# PHP filter_strip_low/high allowing control characters into string

Tags: php, bash

Hey guys you'll have to run this to see what I'm talking about, but I am getting either low or high control characters into my strings using the below code, I recommend running it through a bash terminal as this is how I am seeing glyph like characters.

To my knowledge this should be happening? How are these character escaping the filter?

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$i=0; while ($i++ <= 20)

    echo 'STR: ' .filter_var(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(100), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH) . "\n";
```

Example, I'm not sure if you can see the [] after the character sequence `js*w` but that is pretty much what I'm talking about, it was my opinion that it should have been filtered out with the rest of the high/low stuff

```
STR: &#60;|f)/KZ2|36rb2&#60;.9|X3 js*wjZ6Dp-f8R[/O/VY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW: Strips characters that has a numerical value
>   <32.  FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH: Strips characters that has a numerical
>   value >127.

`ord("[")` returns 91, and `ord("]")` returns 93
so they should not be filtered out

Comment: The `[]` is just an example, I cannot type the real character, its just a little box, but the ord that I get on the character seems to be 127. test is `echo ord(''); die; # 127`